# Google App Engine - Querying for arrays containing a value

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I have a GAE Datastore table with an array field in it (containing a few strings).
I would like to filter this table, based on all array fields that contain a specific string.
How can i do that ?
I didn't see a 'contains' operator in GQL, and the 'in' operator works the other way around.
Do I just need to loop over all entities and do the check myself ?

(P.S. I'm using Python in my work with GAE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use equals, for example:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
  colors = db.StringListProperty()

MyModel(colors=['red', 'blue']).put()
MyModel(colors=['green', 'blue']).put()
MyModel(colors=['red', 'green']).put()

color = 'red'
query = MyModel.gql('WHERE colors = :1', color)
models = query.fetch(10)

assert len(models) == 2
```